# BeagleBone black USB_mass_storage connect to Windows not working

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I have an annoying issue regarding getting USB_mass_storage on BBB to work when connected to Windows
I have created an image :
dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/usb.bin count=64
Formatted it:
mkdosfs /usb.bin -F 32 -I
I have mounted it, copied files to and from it, no problem.
Then I created a USB mass storage :
modprobe g_mass_storage file=./usb.bin stall=0 ro=0
Connected it to a USB port on my Linux, nor problem, I can see and manipulate files
On Windows I can see the drive, the size is correct, but filesystem is not recognized.
With ro=0 I am able to create a partition from within Windows and format it. I can copy files to and from it but when I mount it on BBB I can not see the files copied using Windows. I can still though see the files I copied to the mountpoint on BBB.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

I disabled everything regarding g_multi, including RNDIS, Serial, CDC.
And it works perfectly under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a raw disk image *without a partition table* on the Linux side. Linux doesn't care if it's a file, if it has a partition table, etc.

Windows however gets confused by the lack of partition table. As you noticed.

Having a partition table *is* preferable. What you can do on the Linux side of things:

- `losetup --partscan` - Have the file get processed as a disk with partition table and get devices for each partition
- Mount the partition directly using an offset

In this particular case the latter is probably the quickest. There is only one partition and the offset is known.

`fdisk -l ./usb.bin`

Multiply the `Start` value by the `Units` size. Use it as the offset below:

`mount -o loop,offset=12345 ./usb.bin /mnt`

Make sure to **never access from both sides at the same time** as this will lead to filsystem damage and data loss.

See also e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/69447